# Jedis/Redis SocketTimeout exception on Lua scripts

Tags: lua, redis, jedis

We are using lua scripts to perform batch deletes of data on updates to our DB. Jedis executes the lua script using a pipeline.

```
local result = redis.call('lrange',key,0,12470)
for i,k in ipairs(result) do
   redis.call('del',k)
   redis.call('ltrim',key,1,k)
end

try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
        Pipeline pipeline = jedis.pipelined();
        long len = jedis.llen(table);
         String script = String.format(DELETE_LUA_SCRIPT, table, len);
    LOGGER.info(script);
    pipeline.eval(script);
    pipeline.sync();
    } catch (JedisConnectionException e) {
        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage());
    }
```

For large ranges we notice that the lua scripts slow down and we get SocketTimeOutExceptions.

running redis-cli slowlog displays only the lua scripts that have taken too long to execute.

Is there a better way to do this? is my lua script blocking?

When I use just pipeline to do the batch deletes, the slowlog also returns slow queries.

```
try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
        Pipeline pipeline = jedis.pipelined();
        long len = jedis.llen(table);
        List<String> queriesContainingTable = jedis.lrange(table,0,len);
        if(queriesContainingTable.size() > 0) {
            for (String query: queriesContainingTable) {
                pipeline.del(query);
                pipeline.lrem(table,1,query);
            }
            pipeline.sync();
        }
    } catch (JedisConnectionException e) {
        LOGGER.info("CACHE INVALIDATE FAIL:"+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slowlog is capable of storing top 128 slowlogs alone (can be changed in redis.conf slowlog-max-len 128). So your 1st model of using LUA script is surely a blocking one.

If you delete such a number (12470) one by one it is surely a blocking one as it take more time to complete. Out of the 2 models 2nd one is fine for me (using pipeline), because you avoid the iteration all you do is hitting del query for n times.

You can use del of multiple keys for every 100 or 1000 (whichever you feel as optimal after a small testing). You can group them to a pipeline altogether.

Or if you can do the same without atomicity, you can delete every 100 or 1000 keys at once in a loop, so that it wouldn't be a blocking call.

Try out with different combinations take the metrics and go with the optimized one.